# Given a parallelepiped, how do I find the determinant given vertices?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant

Here are the given vertices of a given parallelepiped...

$ (-1, 0, 0), (0, 4, 0), (-3, -5, 2), (-2, 2, -1) $

I know that first, we should translate all to the origin...

$ (0, 0, 0), (1, 4, 0), (-2, -5, 2), (-1, 2, -1) $

Is the matrix to evaluate the determinant by $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 4 & 0\\-2 & -5 & 2\\-1 & 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ or is this incorrect?

Comment: It looks right.

Comment: Yes it is. The volume is 15.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches: either you transform one point to the origin, or you add a $1$ to every vector:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 0 & -3 & -2\\
0 & 4 & -5 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=
-\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -2 & -1 \\
4 & -5 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & -1
\end{vmatrix}
=
15
$$

So the two solutions differ in their sign. Which doesn't matter if you only care about absolute values, otherwise you should make sure to use one way exclusively. Of course, transforming a matrix doesn't change its determinant, so you might as well write the vectors as rows, the way you do in your question.